# Writing XML files requires large array as string in memory

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I would like to write a *large* data set to an XML file using Python. I'm using lxml like so:

```py
from lxml import etree as ET
import numpy

# a large array
a = numpy.random.rand(100)

xml_file = ET.Element("FooFile")
# yikes:
xml_file.text = "\n".join("{:e}".format(x) for x in a)

# write it to a file
tree = ET.ElementTree(xml_file)
tree.write("out.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

A problem here is that the large array first needs to be converted to a string, which is *much* larger in memory in than the original array, and only then is it written to the file and discarded.

I'd love to skip the intermediate step and write to the file directly myself. Is that possible with lxml or any other XML library? Needless to say I don't want to write my own XML writer.

Instead of `xml_file.txt = "123"` I imagine something like

```
def foo_writer(f):
    f.write("123")

xml_file.writer = foo_writer
```

which is called when `tree.write` is on.

Comment: Perhaps look at stream-based XML writers, e.g., https://pypi.org/project/loxun/

Comment: loxun appears undeveloped for 5 years now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about it. But I guess my general point stands, and you could try to do some looking around for stream-based XML writers. They will have a low memory profile, by virtue of processing data as it comes in from a standard input stream. Hope this helps!